# React App slowly exhausts file descriptor limit on Ubuntu server and crashes in few days

Tags: reactjs, linux, jenkins, serve

I have a **React App** which I am running using **serve** command from **Jenkins** pipeline. One thing to note here is that I configured my Jenkins jobs to run indefinitely for logs. Below screenshot show how my app is running.
[image: Jenkins React App Build process]

Aforesaid setup is running on Ubuntu server and my React App stops once the per-process file descriptor hard limit of 4096 is exhausted.

After a lot of investigation, I found that **index.html** file is getting opened periodically and is not getting closed so File Descriptor count keeps increasing over time. Also, while using app I have observed that there is no increase in count of index.html files i.e. I think its not tied to direct app usage.
[image: React app index html file issue]

Sever Side events is also already implemented for notifications, and I didn't have this issue so not sure if this issue is related to SSE.

Lastly, this started happening since recent release where multiple dependencies were updated and I changed package manager from **npm** to **yarn**.

---

Please note :

- I am not looking for answers suggesting to increase file descriptor limit on Linux but figure out and resolve actual issue.
- This project is built using create-react-app.
- Node version is v14.21.1